# Is there a way to open a text file in SQLiteOpenHelper class in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating an app which has some anime with some quotes related to all anime in it. What I intend to do is make a text file somewhere where I can add anime names which will be used by the app to create tables and store quotes into those. I don't know where I can store that list and how to access it in my SQLiteOpenHelper subclass. Here is my code of the subclass so far:

```
package com.madscientistapps.animenotes

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.content.res.AssetManager
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper

class animeQuotesSQLiteOpenHelper(context:Context, assethelper:AssetManager): SQLiteOpenHelper (context, "animeQuotesDB", null, 1 ) {


    fun addAnime(db: SQLiteDatabase?, resourceId:Int, name:String) {

        var contentvalues = ContentValues()
        contentvalues.put("image_resource_id", resourceId)
        contentvalues.put("animeName", name)

        db?.insert("animeList", null, contentvalues)


    }

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {

        db?.execSQL("CREATE TABLE animeList (" +
                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                "image_resource_id TEXT," +
                "animeName TEXT" +
                ")")

    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: Pass in an `AssetManager` to the constructor of your `SQLiteOpenHelper` subclass. Call `open("list.txt)` on the `AssetManager` to get an `InputStream` on your content. You get an `AssetManager` by calling `getAssets()` on your `Activity` or other `Context`.

Comment: Uhh I passed a context object to class along with an AssetManager as well but whenever I try accessing them in the onCreate function it doesn't work. This is my class declaration:
class animeQuotesSQLiteOpenHelper(context:Context, assethelper:AssetManager): SQLiteOpenHelper (context, "animeQuotesDB", null, 1 )

Comment: If you look under your question, there is an "edit" link. Clicking this will allow you to edit your question to provide your [mcve]. In addition to adding the code, you need to explain, in detail, what "it doesn't work" means.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I have added the code now.

Comment: You do not have any code that refers to `assethelper`. Call `open("list.txt")` on `assethelper` to get an `InputStream` on your content. Use that to read in whatever is in that asset, then use it as you see fit.

Comment: Do I need to create two variable and set them equal to context and assethelper in the init function?

Comment: You could change your constructor parameters from `(context:Context, assethelper:AssetManager)` to `(private val context:Context, private val assethelper:AssetManager)`, so they will be available to you both in an `init` block and from other functions in your class.